# Expression must have class type, but has type

Tags: c++

I have error `Expression must have class type, but has type` at `assert(n == array1.size());`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Array.h"
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const size_t n = 4;
    Array<n, int> array1();
    assert(array1.size() == n);
}
```

And this is `class Array` with `size()` :

```
template <size_t n, typename T>
class Array {
private:
    const size_t _size;
    T* const _allocator;
//...
public:
    Array();
    ~Array();
//...
    size_t size() const;
};
```

Comment: `Array<n, int> array1()` this is the most vexing parse. Remove the `()`

Comment: Either `Array<n, int> array1;` or `Array<n, int> array1{};` will work instead

Comment: It is related to the most vexing, but lets just call this a vexing parse. It is clearly a function definition according to the grammars.